# git gui - add new remote

Tags: git, user-interface

I am trying to initialize remote git and push folder files using Git Gui.
Doing exactly the same sequence in windows with Git Gui works perfectly.
But when doing remote->add in ubuntu, 
name: test
Location: /home/ubuntu/test.git

I get the following error:
fatal: GIT_WORK_TREE (or --work-tree=) not allowed without specifying GIT_DIR (or --git-dir=)
Should I set only GIT_DIR=/home/ubuntu/test.git? And after doing that, repeat the remote->add step ?

Thanks,
Ran

Comment: what app are you using to git? tortoise-git or other?

Comment: Hi, I'm using git gui.

Comment: apology is not known that tool

Comment: which tool are you using ?

Comment: when I'm on Windows I usually use Tortoisegit => https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/; but when I'm working on linux i use command line or Rubymine git plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's been resloved.
I intialized it all with shell commands, and then return to use git gui. It than functions OK.

```
cd <server_dir>
mkdir <name>.git
cd <name>.git
git init --bare

cd <work_dir>
git init
git add *
git commit -m "adding all me files, good luck"
git remote add <git_name> <server_dir>/<name>.git
git push -u <git_name> master
```

Comment: hi i have similar problem in ubuntu git gui and im using your solution but it shows me the same error git_work_tree have you any idea?

Comment: hi, did you try to init everything from shell as I did above ? are you using window or linux ?

Comment: yes i try same as your solution and i'm using ubuntu 15.04

Comment: when you did it using the shell as above, did it work ? If not - what failed on the shell ?